# ScrollPane in TextArea

Tags: java, swing

Here is part of my code:

```
 JFrame window = new JFrame();
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
 JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);  

 private Window()
 {
 createWindow();
 }

 public void createWindow()
 {
 window.setLayout(null);
 window.setVisible(true);
 panel.setVisible(true);
 text.setBounds(20, 100, 320, 270);
 }

 public void update2(String employee) 
 {      
    text.setText(null);
    try
    {
    scanner = new Scanner(employee);
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    text.append(line+"\n");
    }
    revalidate();   
    }
```

I'm wondering how to add scroll bar to TextArea "text". It's a database app and it sends String of data to TextArea. I want the app to show scrollbar (vertical or horizontal) if necessary - too many Strings in TextArea. I have been trying many things but nothing works. Constructor has to be private because I'm using Singleton.

Comment: Have you tried putting the textarea into a jscrollpane?

Comment: @Mr.M have a look at the 4th line, although it's not clear whether it is actually added to the frame.

Comment: You already have the answer in your title, it's just the other way round: you add the text area _into_ the scroll pane and add the scoll pane to the panel/frame/whatever. And btw, don't set the bounds for your components manually but rather use a layout manager.

Comment: It's pretty clear it isn't added to the frame ;) At least in that code you provided. Try window.add(scroll); Though you might want to try scoll.setViewportView(text); first and maybe (depending on your layout) give it a preferred size or something.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `null` layouts. Take a look at [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for better options.

Unless you are not including the part where you add the `Scrollpane` to the `JFrame`, I suggest you do something similar to this

```
frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The `BorderLayout.CENTER` is a position in the default layout for JFrames. Read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_layouts.htm) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, where did you add your scroll to the Frame?

```
window.add(scroll);
window.setVisible (true);
```

JScrollPane is a container that places scrollbars around your component when its needed and also has its own layout. All you need to do when you want to wrap anything into a scroll just pass it into JScrollPane constructor:.

```
 JFrame window = new JFrame();
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
 JScrollPane scroll = new  JScrollPane(text);
```

If the above did not work, use:

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane ();
scroll.getViewport ().setView ( text );
```